# Calling methods from another class Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two classes called 'main' and 'TimerCountDown'. I was try to call a single function 'reset' from 'TimerCountDown' in 'main' class.

This is my TimerCountDown class:

```
public class TimerCountDown extends MovieClip
    {   
        public function TimerCountDown(t:TextField, timeType:String, timeValue:Number, es:String, _documentclass):void
        {
            this.documentclass = _documentclass;
            this.tfTimeDisplay = t;
            if (timeType == "seconds")
            {
                this.timeInSeconds = timeValue;
            }
            if (timeType == "minutes")
            {
                this.timeInSeconds = timeValue * 60;
            }
            this.tfEndDisplayString = es;
            this.startTimer();
        }
            public function reset():void{
            clockCounter.reset();
        }
}
```

How can I create a reference in main class use the reset function in functions of main class? I can only do sth like

```
var myTimerObject:TimerCountDown = new TimerCountDown(timer, "seconds", 40, "0!", this);
```

but have no idea on calling reset function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this :

```
myTimerObject.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may keep a reference of myTimerObject in main class

```
public class Main {


   private var _targetTimerObject:TimerCountDown;

   public function set targetTimerObject(value:TimerCountDown):void {

        _targetTimerObject = value;
   }

   public function someFunction():void {

       if (_targetTimerObject) {
           _targetTimerObject.reset();
       }
   }

}
```